# Insert an email address record (rich.man@yahoo.com) for all employees earning over 35k

Tags: sql

```
EID ContactID   Contact type    Contact value
1   1                    tel    01234212121
1   2                   email   an@emial.com
2   1                    tel    01234212122
3   1                    tel    01234212123
3   2                    mobile 07659121133
3   3                    email  your@email.com
4   1                     tel   01234212124
5   1                     tel   01234212125
6   1                     tel   01234212126
6   2                     mobile    07435123123
7   7                     tel   01234212127

EID Salary
1   £25,000.00
2   £36,000.00
3   £35,000.00
4   £28,000.00
5   £38,000.00
6   £25,000.00
7   £36,000.00
```

Comment: It is traditional to ask a question in a question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for SQL Server. you might have to change the `update` line for other DBMS

```
update a
set [Contact value] = 'rich.man@yahoo.com'
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
on a.EID = b.EID
where a.[Contact type] = 'email'
and b.Salary > 35000
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: @HAMIDD1 If this solved your problem, please choose it as a correct answer. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
update emptable set contactvalue='rich.man@yahoo.com'
where EID in (select EID from salary where salary>35000)
```